# how to add more column in table with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a code that makes a table for me but it makes just one row I want it to make my data in four columns and four rows. How to change my code?

```
var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('foo');
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('bar').html('<a href="http://www.xxx.ir/public/final.php?v=' + data[i] + '&id=' + <? php echo $id ?> +'&date=' + document.getElementById('datepicker1').value + '">' + data[i] + '</a>');   
  table.append(row);
}
```

Comment: Change it how? You need to be more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to put into your columns you could simply use something like:

```
var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('foo');

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('bar');

    var column1 = $('<td></td>').html('CONTENT');
    var column2 = $('<td></td>').html('CONTENT');
    var column3 = $('<td></td>').html('CONTENT');
    var column4 = $('<td></td>').html('CONTENT');

    row.append(column1);
    row.append(column2);
    row.append(column3);
    row.append(column4);

    table.append(row);
}
```